# MATLAB: How to wait for timer stop inside GUI callback?

Tags: matlab, timer, matlab-guide

I use timer object to sample devices via COM drivers from MATLAB 2015b 32bit.
When clicking GUIDE button I need to stop timer, release devices and begin another sequence. But I have no success in implementing waiting for timer stop.

Proposed solutions of wait, waitfor, looping with pause() and drawnow didn't work or I have mistake somewhere.

For example:

```
function timer_step(~,thisEvent)
    disp([datestr(now,'HH:MM:SS.FFF'), ' begin ', thisEvent.Type]);
    pause(1);
    disp([datestr(now,'HH:MM:SS.FFF'), ' end ', thisEvent.Type]);
end

function timer_stop(~,thisEvent)
    global t;
    disp([datestr(now,'HH:MM:SS.FFF'), ' begin ', thisEvent.Type]);
    delete(t);
    t = [];
    disp([datestr(now,'HH:MM:SS.FFF'), ' end ', thisEvent.Type]);
end

function btnStart_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    global t
    t = timer;
    t.StartFcn = @(~,thisEvent)disp([datestr(thisEvent.Data.time,'HH:MM:SS.FFF'),...
    ' executed ', thisEvent.Type]);
    t.TimerFcn = @timer_step;
    t.StopFcn = @timer_stop;
    t.Period = 1;
    t.TasksToExecute = 10;
    t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';
    start(t)


function btnStop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    global t
    disp([datestr(now,'HH:MM:SS.FFF') ' run stop()']);
    stop(t)
    disp([datestr(now,'HH:MM:SS.FFF') ' begin wait to timer finish']);

    % not working solutions:
    drawnow();  
    waitfor(t);
    wait(t);

    % popups new figure and blocks both this callback and timer's callback:
    h = figure;
    uiwait(h)

    % after closing figure continues to
    timeout = 5;
    begin_time = tic();
    while ~isempty(t) && toc(begin_time)<timeout
        disp([num2str(toc(begin_time)),' waiting...']);
        drawnow();
        wait(t);
        pause(1);
    end
    if ~isempty(t)
        disp('got timeout!');
    end
```

Output after pressing Start button and before timer stops, pressing Stop button:

```
>> timer_gui
17:19:29.679 executed StartFcn
17:19:29.681 begin TimerFcn
17:19:30.692 end TimerFcn
17:19:30.694 begin TimerFcn
17:19:31.708 end TimerFcn
17:19:31.710 begin TimerFcn
17:19:31.836 run stop()
17:19:31.837 begin wait to timer finish
% here I get figure pop-up that blocks both callbacks and after closing it continues:
0.0002958 waiting...
1.0116 waiting...
2.0248 waiting...
3.0398 waiting...
4.058 waiting...
got timeout!
17:19:45.955 end TimerFcn
17:19:45.957 begin StopFcn
17:19:45.958 end StopFcn
```

Comment: `stop(t)` already stops the timer. I'm not sure what you're waiting for because when you start waiting, you've already called `stop(t)`. if you want something to happen after the timer stops, put it in the `StopFcn`

Comment: @Suever thanks for your time!

Probably you are right and this is better design decision. I will try to modify the logic.

But I try to understand why timer's callback TimerFcn stacked between lines and continues only when GUI callback finishes. Probably there are some way to release it...

Answer (score 0):

You want to simply stop your timer using `stop(htimer)` and then do all of your cleanup with the `StopFcn` of the timer object.

```
t = timer('StopFcn', @cleanup);

function startButtonCallback(varargin)
    start(t);
end

function stopButtonCallback(varargin)
    stop(t);
end

function cleanup(varargin)
    % Do all of your cleanup stuff here
end
```

Comment: This is what I do, but the problem that Stop button triggers another measurement that should run only after cleanup() but in practice it runs before :( So I try to detect that cleanup finished...

Comment: @AlBaZ In your example above you do not have any cleanup code in your `StopFcn`.

Comment: I oversimplified the example. But it still shows that TimerFcn stacked between:   "17:19:31.710 begin TimerFcn"
and "17:19:45.955 end TimerFcn"

Comment: @AlBaZ Oh it could be that your period is shorter than the time it takes the contents of `TimerFcn` to execute which leads to a backlog of events that have to be fired. Try setting the timer's `BusyMode` to `drop`.